# How to insert square root symbol or unicode characters into SQL Server database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, unicode, sql-insert

I am trying to insert square root symbol `√` into my `SQL Server` database from an `ASP.NET` page. The radical symbol (`&radic;`) gets inserted as letter `v` instead.

Where could I be going wrong?

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the type of the field you're inserting into and collation information, as well as the code you're using to perform the insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database column type should be [nVarChar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186939.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to insert `Unicode` characters.

Also you need to pass values like below:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ColumnName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 1024).Value = txtName.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Column in your table should be able to store unicode characters, try change the type to nvarchar

and while inserting you should use N symbol before the value

let say the column name is `square_root` and table is `test`

```
insert into test(square_root) values(N'√25 = 5')
```

[image]